# React-Redux best practice to change auth state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Probably it's simple, but i'm thinking the best way how to update state when user session (in backend) has expired.

**The user story** - User authenticates against backend service. Session token is saved using `localStorage` and loaded up every time we need authenticated request - so far everything is good.
Then (let's say after 1h) token has expired. How can i dispatch action and update state?

The code fragments:

```
export function getPersons() {
    return (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(fetchDataRequest());

        doFetch('persons', {}, true).then((payload) => {
            dispatch(receiveData(payload.data));
        }).catch((error) => {
            if (error.response && error.response.status===401) {
                dispatch(logoutUser());
            } else {
                dispatch(fetchDataError(error.message));
            }
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see i'm checking the response status here

```
if (error.response && error.response.status===401) {
    dispatch(logoutUser());
}
```

And i'm using a top level function `doFetch` with code below

```
let API_URL = "http://example.com/api/";

export default function doFetch(endpoint, configuration, authenticated) {

    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let config = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

    if (authenticated) {
        if (token) {
            config.headers = { 'Authorization': `${token}` };
        } else {
            return Promise.reject("No token available");
        }
    }

    Object.assign(config, configuration);

    return fetch(API_URL + endpoint, config)
        .then(checkStatus)
}
```

And i want to dispatch the `logoutUser` action here in top level function to avoid of boilerplate in my code. Is it possible at all?
Or i have to return and check the status wherever i'm making request.

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you want a dispatch available in your `doFetch`, you should dispatch `doFetch` like `dispatch(doFetch(...))`. Your `doFetch` will become 
`export default function doFetch(...) {
  return (dispatch) => { /* doFetch code */} 
}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can i handle now `.then(...)` from `getPersons` function, i'm getting .`then()` is not a function.

Comment: Easiest way i see is return `(dispatch) => new Promise((resolve) => { /*doFetch code*/ })` and fire resolve() in your `checkStatus`

Comment: Thanks, saved my day:)